# how to manage mac emacs frames as tabs

Tags: macos, emacs

Just like this:
[image]

**How can I get this?**

1. open emacs and `toggle-frame-fullscreen`
2. click `C-x 5 2` create new frame
3. then `toggle-frame-fullscreen` again

**Known Issues & Solutions:**

1. It seems like a bug, with frame as tab GUI, the buffer text rendering may suck...
2. I didn't install `tabbar` package.
3. [Hammerspoon](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon) may be suitable for this.

Comment: The issue is not described well enough (in English) to answer the question.  Please spend some time editing the question to make it more clear what the problem is and what you are trying to do.  The function `toggle-frame-maximized` will maximize the frame on OSX -- you can even put this inside the `.emacs` or `init.el` file if you want -- i.e., `(toggle-frame-maximized)`.  The tabs that some OSX applications utilize are not built-in to Emacs for OSX -- instead, we use a library called `tabbar`:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10081/browser-style-tabs-for-emacs

Comment: If by chance the problem with the question is due to confusion regarding what a `tab` is, please see the following thread that describes the various components of the Emacs frame:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13583/whats-the-difference-between-a-buffer-a-file-a-window-and-a-frame  And, here is an example of how to create a 3-window layout:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26967/open-several-files-in-a-specifc-layout-with-a-shortcut/26970#26970

Comment: @lawlist use `toggle-frame-fullsceen` command to fullscreen and then create new frame, then `toggle-frame-fullsceen` again, after that two frames will appear in a single GUI without installing `tabbar` package. So, is there a way to manage frames as tabs builtin? And thank for your help!

Comment: There is no way to manage frames as tabs with the GUI version of Emacs on OSX -- sorry. What you seek is not an available feature.  A possible alternative might be to use just one (1) frame *only* and set up tabs (within that frame) with different window layouts -- e.g., using the `elscreen` package.  Emacs 25 has major bug fixes for frame sizing and placement on OSX, so if you haven't upgraded already, you should consider doing so.  Another alternative is to place frames exactly lined up on top of each other, which can be done programmatically to the exact pixel specification using Emacs 25.

Comment: I'm using Emacs 25.1.1 already, I'll take a look at `elscreen`. Anyway, Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm on emacs 25.2.1, and was enjoying using tabs under fullscreen, and using command-` to switch between tabs (frames). But desktop-save / desktop-read are not tab-aware, so restored my session as separate un-tabbed frames. If OSX Emacs included the Cocoa "Window" menu, I could recombine them with Window->Merge All Windows, but instead, I'm left searching for an emacs command or package to do the same- which brings me back to the original question (or some version of it)- can emacs mange its frames within native OSX tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the opposite issue.  As it happens, Emacs on my laptop would create a native macOS tab wherever `make-frame-command` (`C-x 5 2`) is called.  Strangely enough same was not happening on my desktop.

Turns out the culprit is System Preferences->General->Prefer Tabs settings.

[image: System Preferences->General]

When set to the default value of "in full screen", `make-frame` will create tabs only in full screen. Other options are "always and "never".  Turns out my laptop was set to always.

Since does not always make sense for the default behavior of Preview and Emacs to match, the following lines in `~/.emacs.d/init.el` will prevent tabs from being created.

```
  (setq mac-frame-tabbing nil)
```

There are also `mac-move-tab-to-new-frame` and other `mac-...` commands to deal with native tabs.